# Displaying Large images same as twitter using twitter photo card

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter photo card(its's approved)  for my application. When I am trying to post large size(for ex: 540X810 in px ) it displays 'View photo' link on Twitter without displaying image. How do I solve this?

In Twitter if we post the same image directly it shows at least half the image then displays 'View photo' link below.

Comment: Can you give us some example tweets? Or the code you're using?

Comment: Please check this image (http://tdoc.s3.amazonaws.com/Twitter.png) , you can understand what I want to do exactly.

Comment: I solved this issue without using twitter card, using statuses/update_with_media API call.

Answer (score 1):

Vamshichalla, you've identified a significant issue with implementing the Photo Card on twitter; the Photo Card **will not show your image** in an expanded view if you are hosting it on your own server.  This issue came up in the [Twitter forums](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo) where employees explained that photos will be hidden in the timeline **unless** they originate from twitter's servers (typically pbs.twimg.com).

There are two solutions to fix the hidden Photo Card photo in timeline.

### Use the Twitter API

One option is using the Twitter API to upload an image.  This seems like the route you took as of Sep 29 2014.

### Upload Photo Twitter's Compose & Find the src tag

A second option is uploading your images using twitter's standard photo upload tool.  That process [is described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEdN.jpg) where you compose a tweet and upload images to your account.  The final step is to make note of the source address of these images on the twitter server.  You can then use this src in your card so the image will appear expanded in the timeline.  Please see the Photo Card docs if there are questions about setting up the card meta-data itself.

### Summary

Discovering the need to host your images on Twitter's servers is **not** well publicized as of the time of this writing.  The solution is to upload the image to Twitter's servers.  I hope this answer saves other people valuable time.

PS - Organizations that have an advertising relationship with Twitter may not have to follow these steps.

### Other Troubleshooting (if your image doesn't show at all)

Please note that there are other issues that could be preventing your image from showing at all which are covered in Twitter's troubleshooting guide.  These mainly involve if your hosted address has not yet requested approval.  Use the Validator Tool on your card for that -- after preview if it fails the authentication requirement it gives you an option to request approval.  The other common issue would be if you have a robots.txt (a file that is used to tell web crawlers where to look for meta-data) that is telling the Twitter crawler to stay away from your images.

Comment: Stack Exchange did not allow me to post all relevant links above.  Please see the [Validator Tool](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), [Trouble Shooting Guide](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting), [Photo Card docs](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo), and [Media Upload API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media)